# Azure CDN Endpoint : Enabling HTTPS for default custom domain mediaservice-inct.streaming.media.azure.net

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

Azure by default creates a custom domain for Media Service with servicename"-inct.streaming.media.azure.net".

When CDN Endpoint is mapped to this domain and HTTPS enablement is done with CDN Managed certificate, we are seeing the following status;

[image: CDN HTTPS Enablement]

Now, this custom domain is not managed by us. How are we supposed to make CNAME record entries and mapping with the endpoint?

Is Azure or CDN provider is going to do this on our behalf?
How long do we need to wait for domain validation?

Comment: Hello I'm a bit confused by your question here. Azure CDN is supposed to be enabled by default for the default Streaming Endpoint. See documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-portal-manage-streaming-endpoints#enable_cdn . Can you describe what you are trying to do exactly ?

Comment: I am trying to add custom domain (also created by default) servicename"-inct.streaming.media.azure.net" with HTTPS enablement to the StandardVerizon Streaming Endpoint. Hmm.. is this not needed?

Comment: I don't think so if CDN is enabled by default for the streaming service.

Comment: The documentation says that it creates streaming service by default, but in the Streaming Endpoint of the Media Service, it shows CDN was disabled. That's why I was trying to map it to CDN.